# Universal Search for Attributes

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to search in the values stored under my Attributes.

For example, I have a few attributes under the Cases screen. I want to search the value of these attributes from Universal Search. So when I do a universal search, it brings up this case.

I know we can include `PXSearchable` for the Notes. But as attributes are stored in CSAnswers tables, I am not sure how to include it. Also, CSAnswers is not available for Rebuild Index screen (SM209500)

I have the below code, it's not working.

```html
public class CRCaseMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
{
  #region PXNotes
  [PXNote()]
  [PXSearchable(SM.SearchCategory.CR, "{0}", new Type[] { typeof(CRCase.caseCD) }, new Type[] { typeof(CSAnswers.value) },
   Line1Format = "{0}{1}", Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(CRCase.caseCD),typeof(CRCase.subject) }
  )]
  public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
  #endregion
}
```

[image]

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this on the InventoryItem with an unbound field in a DAC extension to apply a PXDBScalar to retrieve the value and then incorporate that field in [PXNote].  PXDBScalar allows you to lookup a value from another DAC based on some value in the current DAC.  I struggled a bit with this because I wanted to use Current in the Where clause, but Current<> is not used in this case.  The PXDBScalar in this example will lookup the CSAnswer attribute value for my InventoryItem for my AttributeID "SITEM".

To pick up the specific AttributeID, I defined a PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant with the specific AttributeID for the PXDBScalar to reference since it needs a type in the use of PXDBScalar.

```
public sealed class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
{
    #region SItem
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "S Item")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<CSAnswers.value,
        Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<InventoryItem.noteID>,
        And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<AttribSItem>>>>))]
    public string SItem { get; set; }
    public abstract class sItem : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<sItem> { }
    #endregion

    public class AttribSItem : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<AttribSItem>
    {
        public AttribSItem() : base("SITEM") { }
    }
}
```

In the PXSearchable Attribute of NoteID, I added reference to my PXString field above.

```
#region NoteID  
[PXSearchable(SearchCategory.IN, "{0}: {1}",
    new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.itemType), typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
    new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr), typeof(InventoryItem.body), typeof(InventoryItemExt.sItem) },
    NumberFields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
    Line1Format = "{0}{1}", Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD), typeof(InventoryItem.baseUnit) },
    Line2Format = "{0} {1}", Line2Fields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr), typeof(InventoryItemExt.sItem) },
    WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<InventoryItem.itemStatus>, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>)
    )]
[PXNote]
public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

[image: Universal Search for Attribute]

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the needed values(delimited by ';' for example) in a new field from Cases header part from Persist function. Then it's necessary to do standard steps related to modifying the PXSearchable attribute for the newly added string field. After that, you'll have something like this 'Generic Inquiry; Other Value1; Other Value2' and when you'll search 'Generic Inquiry' the corresponding record will show up. 
I've done it for item alternate ids from Stock Items Cross-Reference tab.

Collecting part:

```
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(Action baseAction)
{
    using (PXTransactionScope tranScope = new PXTransactionScope())
    {
        InventoryItem item = Base.Item.Current;
        if (item != null && Base.itemxrefrecords.Cache.IsDirty)
        {
            string alternateIDs = string.Empty;
            foreach (INItemXRef crossRef in Base.itemxrefrecords.Select())
            {
                alternateIDs = string.IsNullOrEmpty(alternateIDs) ? crossRef.AlternateID : alternateIDs + "; " + crossRef.AlternateID;
            }
            item.GetExtension<BZInventoryItemExt>().UsrBZAlternateIDs = alternateIDs;
            Base.Item.Update(item);
        }

        baseAction();
        tranScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

DAC field:

```
#region NoteID Extended
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSearchableAttribute))]
[PXSearchable(PX.Objects.SM.SearchCategory.IN, "{0}: {1}",
new Type[] {
    typeof(InventoryItem.itemType),
    typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
new Type[] {
    typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
    typeof(BZInventoryItemExt.usrBZAlternateIDs) },
NumberFields = new Type[] {
    typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
    typeof(BZInventoryItemExt.usrBZAlternateIDs) },
Line1Format = "{0}{1}{2}",
Line1Fields = new Type[] {
    typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
    typeof(INItemClass.descr),
    typeof(InventoryItem.baseUnit) },
Line2Format = "{0}",
Line2Fields = new Type[] {
    typeof(InventoryItem.descr) },
WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<InventoryItem.itemStatus>,
    NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>)
)]
public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
#endregion
```